# ArcGIS Field Editor if/else syntax with python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000539, syntax

I am just starting with Python and ArcGIs so here is my question:

I have the column "DB_Low" (Type "Long") and want to fill a new column by changing values. The new column will be a Float-Type field.

So here is what I tried so far:

```
if !DB_Low! == 0:

  return 0

else:

  return  !DB_Low! + 2.25
```

But I get the Error: 000539 SyntaxError, invalid syntax (, line 1)

Can someone tell me the mistake in my code?

Comment: FYI quite often I will check the help file right from the field calculator for small syntax/formatting and function references.

Answer (score 2):

In the code block window of the field calculator, try using:

```
def new(DB_Low):
    if DB_Low == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return DB_Low + 2.25
```

And then in the expression window:

```
new(!DB_Low!)
```